# Debug and Release Build works fine but the Distribution/AdHoc Crashes

Tags: iphone, ios4, app-store

HI there,
Some users of my application have reported me that my application is no longer working. It closes just after launching it.

I have been trying to identify the crash for days with no luck using builds debug and release and testing it in several devices. This morning I was surprised when I was able to reproduce the problem by generating a AdHoc version and installing it on my iPhone.

I have already tried to remove all the custom configurations and recreate them using a copy of the release version but it did not work.

I got this error below when I was running in the simulator and the crash reports also points to the same place...

**Detected an attempt to call a symbol in system libraries that is not present on the iPhone:fwrite$UNIX2003 called from function -[My7zipExtract extract7zFile:]**

So, my question is: What is the difference between build Debug/Release and Distribution (App Store/Ad Hoc). I have double checked everything and the only difference are the certificates.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm having precisely the same problem right now. I copied my Debug Xcode configuration to create the AdHoc one, adding entitlements and changing the certificate.

Doing good old printf-debugging ;) i found that the c++ constructors seem to be called differently / not called at all on the iPhone when using the AdHoc build.